# What does it mean by "gradient flow" in the context of neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, math, definitions, gradient

Several research papers and textbooks (e.g. [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9709/8/3/53)) contain the phrase "**gradient flow**" in the context of neural networks.

I am confused about whether it has any rigorous and formal way of understanding or not. What is the flow referring to here?

Comment: Note that although this is seemingly not the way it's used in the paper you link, gradient flows in the context of optimization generally refer to a continuous-time analogue of gradient descent; see, e.g., here: https://francisbach.com/gradient-flows/

Answer (score 3):

It has. Gradient flow or more generally [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)#Time-dependent_ordinary_differential_equations) is a well known concept in maths. Say we have a function $f:\mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and a function $\theta:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ such that the ODE
$$
\partial_t \theta(t) = f(\theta(t))
$$
exists for any initial choice $\theta(0)\in\mathbb R^n$ uniquely. Then i think the naming comes from the following informal description. Lets imagine the case $n=2$ then $\mathbb R^2$ is a plane. Now you drop $\theta(0)$ somewhere on this plane and wait some time $t$ to see where the $\theta(0)$ will *flow* to. You can also draw the trajectories for multiple starting points $\theta(0)$ which will often give you an image that looks like a flow of a liquid.

In the case of the ANN $f$ would be the negative gradient of the costfunction with respect to the paramter-vector $\theta$ and gradient descent would be an approximation of the gradient flow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea of what that means: Gradient flow is an abstract term to describe properties of the gradient. The gradient is calculated by propagating the error backwards through the networks, therefore it kind of *flows* from the last to the first layer. Depending on network architecture and loss function the flow can behave differently.

One popular kind of undesirable gradient flow is the **vanishing gradient**. It refers to the gradient norm being very small, i.e. the parameter updates are very small which slows down/prevents proper training. It often occurs when training very deep neural networks. Residual connections can help, because they bypass operations that reduce gradient magnitude.

The exact opposite would be **exploding gradients** where your gradient-norm is very large which leads to unstable training and the weights inside the network can't follow a stable trajectory to the optimum. This often occurs in the context of recurrent neural networks.

[Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/the-challenge-of-vanishing-exploding-gradients-in-deep-neural-networks/) is a nice article on vanishing/exploding gradients.

A general way to phrase this is that the gradient reveals properties about the loss function which you are optimizing (as it is the derivative). **A noisy or heavily oscillating loss function usually implies an undesirable gradient flow**.

Thinking about these properties plays an important role in network and loss function design.
For example, the root function $\sqrt{\cdot}$ has a very large derivative when approaching zero, so having a $\sqrt{\cdot}$ in the network or the loss function can lead to exploding gradients.